# Solve can not find intersection indicated by plotting two functions

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

[image: solve/reduce vs graph]

`Solve` clearly shows the intersection at `t = 9`while the plot shows the intersection at `t = 10`. How am I being an idiot here?

```
x[t_] = 20 Cos[(8 π)/15 t]^2;
y[t_] = 10 Sin[(4 π)/15 t];
z[t_] = 16/675 t^3;
r[t_] = {x[t], y[t], z[t]};

ct3[t_] = {25 - 20 (t - 9), 20 - 11.33974596 (t - 9), (640/27) (t - 9)};

Solve[r[t] == ct3[t], {t}]

N[r[10]]
N[ct3[10]]
```

After clearing my kernel the solve function no longer returns any answer at all, though an evaluation of the two functions at t==10 shows an identical position vector.

Comment: "how am I being an idiot here?" By not giving enough information to reproduce the problem.  Construct a [minimal example](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2126/12) and post it as copyable code (not a screenshot).

Comment: I'm not certain the graph is showing the intersection at 10... Reading graphs is hard. Draw a plane at t=9 to check.

Comment: Please clean your screen.  It looks rather grotty.

Comment: Hint: Compare {N[r[10]],N[ct3[10]]} and {N[r[10]]-N[ct3[10]]}

Answer (score 1):

You problem arises from the inexact quantity 11.33974596. Because of the inexactness, the two curves come very close together but do not mathematically intersect. You can find the point where they are very close with `NSolve`.

```
x[t_] := 20 Cos[(8 π)/15 t]^2
y[t_] := 10 Sin[(4 π)/15 t]
z[t_] := 16/675 t^3
r[t_] := {x[t], y[t], z[t]}
ct3[t_] := {25 - 20 (t - 9), 20 - 11.33974596 (t - 9), (640/27) (t - 9)}

NSolve[r[t] == ct3[t], {t}, WorkingPrecision -> 5]
```

> `{{t -> 10.000}}`